# creating a function that outputs linked text with different links on a single line, mapping links onto text if link exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

Hi all I am writing a function that will take in a string of names, then for each name if it is in a list, it will take the text of the name and add a link to it, if it is not it will simply display the text. The aim is to have these all in a single line when displayed.

```
function founderslinked(foundernames,foundersqueryname){
  var foundernames=foundernames.split(", ");
   var founderslinkstring='';
  foundernames.map((foundername)=>{
    var foundernamelower=foundername.toLowerCase();
    var foundernamelower=foundernamelower.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    if(founderqueryname.indexOf(foundernamelower>=0)){
      var thelink=`${links.index}/about/contributors/${foundernamelower}`;
      var thelink="<a href="+thelink+">"+foundername+"</a>";
      var thelink.innerHTML=thelink;

      founderslinkstring=founderslinkstring+","+thelink.

    }else{
         founderslinkstring+=founderslinkstring+" "+foundername;



   }
 
    
  })
return{founderslinkstring
}
}
```

founder names will be a string of the format "John Doe, Matt Jones, Frank Smith", and founderqueryname will be an array of the form ['john-doe','frank-smith].
The founderqueryname array is an array of the queries, of the people that have a personal page; if a query with their first and last name is in founderqueryname that means they have a personal page and it can be linked to.

I am essentially wanting to display all their names on a single line with this function. so I want to input the string of names and the array of queries. if there is a query with their name on it I want to add their name with a link to the single line we will display. if there is no query with their name I want to add only the text without a link to the line. using the above array and string, the function when called on the string and array

```
{founders linked(namesoffounders,queryoffounders);}
```

should display something like:

```
John Doe( text and link),Matt Jones(only text no link), Frank Smith(text and link)
```

"thelink" is essentially the pathway to the persons page if they have one and I am adding their name with a link to their page if they have a page. however this does not work. I am only getting the text as strings any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Edit: as per @jaramanda x suggestion I got it to render by using the fixes he suggested I then ran:

```
{JSON.stringify(founderslinked(thelistoffounders,thelistoffounderqueries))}
```

however the above renders into text like this:

[image]

The names and text are displayed so are the proper links however, there is no, they do not show up as actual links any ideas?

Comment: Howdy, can you please clarify what is the issue ?

Comment: `founderqueryname` is not defined, `var thelink.innerHTML=thelink;` is a syntax error, `links` is not defined, why are you using `foundernames.map` if you aren't returning anything in the callback, use `foundernames.forEach`, `founderslinkstring=founderslinkstring+","+thelink.` is a syntax error - the trailing `.` - so, the code you've written is nowhere near running - `foundersqueryname.indexOf(foundernamelower >= 0)` check the position of the brackets

Comment: and `founderslinkstring += founderslinkstring + " " + foundername;` is probably not what you want

Comment: one more ... `thelink.innerHTML = thelink` ... `thelink` is a **string**, strings do not have a `innerHTML` property (you can add one, but it won't do what you think it does)

Comment: last one: `var thelink="<a href="+thelink+">"+foundername+"</a>";` results in `<a href=xxxxxxxx>` ... you should have quotes around the href value (though, it may work without them - better to have the quotes than not) - since you say *I am only getting the text as strings* - given all the issues above, most of which would prevent the code from running, I would suggest that you've posted the wrong code, because that code would produce syntax errors, and no result

Comment: can you look at my updated edit please @rigojr ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(founderslinked(thelistoffounders,thelistoffounderqueries))` ... is probably not what you want to be using as HTML - you probably just want to use `founderslinked(thelistoffounders,thelistoffounderqueries).founderslinkstring` for HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this fixes ALL the issues in your code, and produces the expected output

Though I added a dummy `links` with an `index` property, since that is completely absent from your code

```js
var links = {
    index: 'xxx'
};
function founderslinked(foundernames, foundersqueryname) {
    return {
        founderslinkstring: foundernames.split(", ")
        .map((foundername) => {
            const foundernamelower = foundername.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
            if (foundersqueryname.includes(foundernamelower)) {
                return `<a href="${links.index}/about/contributors/${foundernamelower}">${foundername}</a>`;

            } else {
                return foundername;
            }

        })
        .join(',')
    };
}
console.log(founderslinked("John Doe, Matt Jones, Frank Smith", ['john-doe', 'frank-smith']));
```

Comment: hi the links is an import. applying your code I try to display it using <p>these are the founders {founderslinked(listoffounders,listoffounderqueries)}</p>. however it returns an error saying : Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {founderslinkstring}). any ideas? thanks alot, you've already helped me make a great amount of progress.

Comment: No idea @lambdaepsilon - the code I wrote is your code with all the syntax errors fixed, and refactored to be "better" (in my opinion) - if you had "partially" working code and it didn't produce the error you now have, then I have no idea why this is the case

Comment: I got it to render and the links are correct, as are the text, however still the text does not show up as linked text. my code was not rendering before I had in fact added a wrong version of the code before. can you look at my updated edit please @Jaromanda X

Comment: You're JSON.stringifying the result and what to use that as HTML? that doesn't look right at all ... `founderslinked(thelistoffounders,thelistoffounderqueries).founderslinkstring` looks more like what you want ... but in that case, there's no reason to return an object from the function, rather, just the string

Comment: thanks alot. I am trying to display it with dangerously set html but it is simply not rendering any clue on how to do this? I am getting  Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. the command is dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: founderslinked(thelinkedfounders,foundersinpeoplequery).founderslinkstring}}.